# Drools bean validation using constraints from data base

Tags: java, drools, bean-validation, business-rules

I have a requirement to write the drools program to validate a bean properties based on the constraints stored in data base. For example:

```
class Product {
    private String description;
    private String partNumber;
    private int price;
   //getters and setters
}

the constraints for field are stored in db like

description: mandatory, lengthMax=200
partNumber: mandatory, lengthMax=50
price: number, >0
```

the above constraint will vary product to product based on the industry domain.

I need to insert the product into working memory and in rules, based on the product fetch the constraints from db
and validate the object and report the result.

I do not know how to achieve this in drools. like validating the properties dynamically. am looking for any guidance or example.

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: I do not know how to achieve this in drools. like validating the properties dynamically. am looking for any guidence or example.

Comment: How much is dynamical? Just the values 200, 50, 0?

Comment: it is fully dynamic, this is a ecommerce product data.Product will contain many fields,  it varies product to product and also by country to country.

Comment: It has nearly 150 fields, nearly 15 countries. if some fileds are optional for some country, mandatory 
for some other countries and the filed length varies by language.

Answer (score 0):

Sketchy - more details ought to be available.

I guess that, given a country, you know the fields and their properties and constraints.

One option is to use a simple template for each country that generates the rule. Parameters (limits) can be added as parameters for template expansion.

You may write your own code for generating a rule, given the information for a country.

Fact types can be generated as well, one for each country. Reflection may help. - Alternatively, it's also possible to store all properties in a Map.

*Edit*
I'm assuming that all Product properties are stored in a Map.
Assuming you have, for country XY, a DB entry with name "description" mandatory "true" and maximum length 200, you would insert a generic fact `StringValue` and have a rule

```
$p: Product()
$s: String() from $p.getMap().get( "description" )
StringValue( $s.length() <= maxLen )
```

If it fires, the Product is validated. Other generic facts are required for numeric properties, optional properties, etc.

Comment: Dear Laune, thanks for the reply. you are correct, for the given country, fields and constraints known. Is there any way I rules, I can fetch the constraints object list from db and apply that constraints on the inserted facts? in that way we can write one set rules but can validate any countires.

Comment: for Example: 
 Product($contryId:countryId,$productId:productId)
 Constraint() for constrainstsService.fetch(productId,countryId);
 apply the constraints on the product field.

Comment: Dear Laune. Thank you very much. I will try the same with fetching the constraints from db  using from.